# eDrawings API via Excel

Tags: excel, vba, solidworks

I am attempting to use the edrawings VBA api via excel. I have downloaded the edrawings SDK and it seems as though the api only runs through a user form. I have made a few vba macros for solidworks via excel but unlike solidworks there is very limited documentation. I simply want to make a connection to the API, after which I should be able to take it from there.

For right now I would simply like to open up a solidworks drawing in edrawings via excel. So something like the following:

```
Sub OpenDrawing()

Dim xlBook As Workbook
Dim xlsheet As Worksheet
Dim eDraw As New EModelViewControl
Dim FilePath As String

Set xlBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set xlsheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)

FilePath = Range("B1").Value

eDraw.OpenDoc FilePath, False, False, True, ""

End Sub
```

As an example, Range B1 is the following "C:\ _EngVault\000S\090\090-40400-01.SLDDRW". I have activated the EModelView2018 Type Library and running edrawings 2018. Again, once I can figure out how to connect to the program I should be good but I am unable to make it that far.

Also, do I need a user form for this or did I misunderstand?

Thank you in advance,

FFS88

Comment: see this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541047/how-to-open-solidworks-run-macro-and-close-solidworks-from-vb-net-script)

Comment: and [this](https://forum.solidworks.com/message/663391#comment-663391)

Answer (score 0):

> Also, do I need a user form for this or did I misunderstand?

Yes the eDrawings API is an OLE programming interface to eDrawings and is implemented as a Microsoft ActiveX control.

So you have to place the ActiveX control on your form and access the api through this control:

```
Me.EModelViewControl1.OpenDoc path_to_edrawings_file, False, False, False, ""
```

It is not possible to start a new instance or connect to a running instance as you may know from the SOLIDWORKS API.