# How to open Solidworks, run macro, and close Solidworks from vb.net script?

Tags: vba, vb.net, windows-10, solidworks

I am running a VBA Macro in solidworks that stops working and requires me to restart Solidworks after exactly 478 loop-itterations every time I run it.

Inside my loop, I open an STEP file, verify it, and then save it as an STL file. It appears as if Solidworks is struggling to open more than a fixed number of files in the same session.

My plan was to write a VB.NET script outside of Solidworks that can automatically restart the application without my intervention every X number of ittwerations, so I can process the thousands of files I have without my intervention.

VB.NET console script that closes and reopens Solidworks for me, whenever 477 itterations are reached, and then continues the macro from where it has left off.

The folders with my files are numbered, e.g.

```
c:\data\0\file.STEP
c:\data\1\file.STEP
c:\data\2\file.STEP
...
c:\data\20000\file.STEP
```

Specifically, I am looking for the VB.NET code that does the following:

1. Open Solidworks
2. Call an existing Macro-Script (possibly set a variable that lets me continue where I left of processing the data)
3. Close Solidworks

Comment: There's a free macro runner for Solidworks that you can use instead of in-house solution - #Task by CentralInnovation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) first you need to open solidworks and the file you want to process:
**Open Assembly Document Example (VB.NET)**
http://help.solidworks.com/2017/english/api/sldworksapi/open_assembly_document_example_vbnet.htm

2) you will need the **openMacro2** function.
Here is a link with an example
https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/79502

3) then close all documents with the 
**CloseAllDocuments** Method
http://help.solidworks.com/2017/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ISldWorks~CloseAllDocuments.html

4) then exit solidworks with the **ExitApp** Method
https://help.solidworks.com/2017/english/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ISldWorks~ExitApp.html

note: if you installed the api module you will find all needed examples in the apihelp.chm file which is located by default in:
C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS Corp\SOLIDWORKS\api

I took the liberty choosing version 2017 since you didn't mention the version you are using. But all examples should work on later versions too. If you are on an earlier version and you cannot find for instance openDoc7, then look at openDoc6 or openDoc5... until you find the number that is available on your system.

Comment: Hi Eddy, Thank you so much for your response. I will try that today. My Solidworks Version is 2018, but I doubt the docs differ on that.

Comment: Yes, change the 2017 for 2018 and you are good to go

Comment: Ï curious about the underlying goal of your questions. What is it exactly you want to do 477 times?

Comment: Hi Eddy, I want to itterate over thousands of cad files load them into Solidworks, verify their geometry, and save them as STL files. It just so happens that Solidworks stops working after 478 loop-itterations i.e. after opening 478 files. So, I needed a way to restart it automatically, since otherwise I'd manually oclosing and reopening SW, and rerunning the script over and over again to work through all my data.

Comment: Have you tried using task scheduler? I doubt the number 478 is an amount you can rely on.

Comment: please add the additonal info in your first post because your question is on hold for being too broad. It can be deleted by moderators if your edits are not specific enough.

Comment: Surprisingly, after having run my script already over 30 times manually (each time after restarting Solidworks), the problem consistently arose after 478 loop-itterations, i.e. after opening a total of 479 files. On the 480th file I receive an error and Solidworks stops working propperly.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I did not include the error message in my question because I was worried it direct the answers in the wrong direction. The error comes from the swApp object being equal to "nothing": `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set`. Now, in all previous itterations that same object, following the same loop was set, also, the file that I am trying to load exists, and will flawlessly process if I just restart Solidworks. Giving up on trying to fix Solidworks, I decided to ask a questions that would provide me with a workable alternative.

Comment: Ok thanks for the full explanation. Success with your project!